# Фокус на кнопке

Tags: html, css, форма

```css
.modal-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 78px;
    right: 90px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}    

.modal-close::before,
.modal-close::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 24px;
    height: 3px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f0595a;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.modal-close::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.modal-close::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.modal-close:hover::before,
.modal-close:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-close:focus::before,
.modal-close:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.visually-hidden {
   position: absolute;
   clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
   width: 1px;
   height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button class="modal-close" type="button">
   <span class="visually-hidden">Закрыть</span>
</button>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с какой ошибкой может быть связан подобный фокус на кнопке закрытия формы?

[image: обводка не по контуру кнопки]

Comment: Причин может быть много, как минимум в вёрстке, без кода сложно что-нибудь сказать

Comment: спасибо, добавила

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```
.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 78px;
  right: 90px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.modal-close::before,
.modal-close::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 24px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f0595a;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.modal-close::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.modal-close::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.modal-close:hover::before,
.modal-close:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-close:focus::before,
.modal-close:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

```html
<button class="modal-close" type="button">
   <span class="visually-hidden">Закрыть</span>
</button>
```

Comment: А обязательны ли свойства `margin`, `padding` и `border`? По идее одного `overflow` с головой

Comment: @Arthur - margin обязательно, padding и border - не обязательно

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю что стоит заменить свойства у класса `visibility-hidden`:

```
position: absolute;
clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
```

на обычный `display: none`, потому как те свойства не скрывают полностью `span`, лежащий внутри кнопки.

```css
.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 78px;
  right: 90px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.modal-close::before,
.modal-close::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 24px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f0595a;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.modal-close::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.modal-close::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.modal-close:hover::before,
.modal-close:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-close:focus::before,
.modal-close:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.visually-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="modal-close" type="button">
   <span class="visually-hidden">Закрыть</span>
</button>
```

Comment: В данном случае лучше так не делать, нет смысла использовать данный блок с текстом. Таким способом, вы скрываете информацию, которая не будет доступной для читателей экрана

Comment: @soledar10, понял-принял